# How do I have a trait as a owned field of a struct?

Tags: rust, struct, traits, borrow-checker

I'm fairly new to Rust, I was tying to implement a struct that could have different structs that implemented a common trait as a field

In traditional programming languages with garbage collector I would have implemented it like this:

```rust
pub struct MemoryMapper {
    regions: Vec<Region>,
}

trait MemoryMappable: Sized {
    
}

pub struct Region {
    device: dyn MemoryMappable,
    start: u32,
    end: u32,
    remap: bool
}
```

But here I have the following compilation error:

```
the size for values of type `(dyn MemoryMappable + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn MemoryMappable + 'static)`
only the last field of a struct may have a dynamically sized type
change the field's type to have a statically known size
```

I have tried making Sized a supertrait of MemoryMappable, but it still gives me issues with the following code:

```
pub fn map(&mut self, device: dyn MemoryMappable, start: u32, end: u32, remap: bool) -> &Region {
        self.regions.insert(0, Region{device, start, end, remap});
        return self.regions.get(0).unwrap();
}
```

```
the trait `MemoryMappable` cannot be made into an object
`MemoryMappable` cannot be made into an object
```

Because from [Rust documentation about object safety](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety)

> Sized must not be a supertrait. In other words, it must not require Self: Sized.

I have no idea of how to go about this at this point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fields of `Sized` structs can exist on the stack, and so must have a known size at compile time. This is what the `Sized` error is saying.

`dyn Trait` is "any type that implements `Trait`. So what is its size? Well, it depends on what the underlying type is.

Therefore, `dyn Trait` never implements `Sized`, even if `Trait` has `Sized` as a supertrait (all this does is guarantee that any type that implements `Trait` also implements `Sized`, but you still don't know *which one* it is).

In fact, making `Sized` a supertrait of `Trait` is how you opt-out of object safety, which makes it impossible to construct a `dyn Trait`.

Instead, the way you get around this is by using a pointer-like type:

- `Box<dyn Trait>` creates an owned pointer
- `&dyn Trait` creates a reference
- `Arc<dyn Trait>` creates a reference counted pointer
- etc.

The choice of pointer type depends on your use case, but in most scenarios, `Box<dyn Trait>` is fine, and is a good starting point.

Comment: "Fields of a struct exist on the stack, and so must have a known size at compile time." this is not true. A struct is allowed to have an field whose size is unknown at compile time, but it must be the last field. See [this example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b76b0f367f7668bce664d9e4c767d9b6), and note that if you exchange the order of the fields, it doesn't work.

Comment: Yep, I guess it's more accurate to say "fields of `Sized` structs ...", thanks

Comment: You got your reasoning the wrong way around, their size is known at compile time (as required by `Sized`), and so they can exist on the stack.